# Showing that the Poisson process is characterized by five properties

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

[Klenke](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000472) defines the Poisson process as a family of non-negative integer valued random variables with independent increments, whose increments are distributed according to the Poisson distribution ([Definition 5.33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxeZn.jpg)). He proceeds to prove that the Poisson process can be characterized by five properties ([Theorem 5.34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxeZn.jpg), [the five properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJmtk.jpg) P1-P5). In order to prove the direction "If a process satisfies P1-P5, it is a Poisson process" ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1X0p.jpg)), he appeals to the [Poisson approximation theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB3vV.jpg). This theorem assumes a collection of numbers $\left(p_{n,k}\right)\subseteq\left[0,1\right]$ that satisfy two conditions:
$$\left(i\right)\space\space \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_{n,k}\in\left(0,\infty\right)$$
$$\left(ii\right)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_{n,k}^2=0$$
Accordingly, in the proof of Theorem 5.34 Klenke defines a collection of numbers $\left(p_{n,k}\right)=\left(p_n\right)$ and shows that they satisfy condition $\left(i\right)$ (this takes place five lines from the end, where it is shown that $\alpha t=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n2^n=\lim \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} p_n$). However, condition $\left(ii\right)$ isn't verified, which brings me to wonder: why does condition $\left(ii\right)$ hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, as $p_{n,k}=\frac{\lambda}n$ when $k\leq n$ and $0$ otherwise,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}p_{n,k}^2=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\lambda^2}{n^2}=\frac{\lambda^2}n,$$
which gives the wanted result, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks, but what's $\lambda$? Are you referring to [Theorem 5.34's proof](http://imgur.com/a/pjEji#2) or to the comment preceding the [Poisson approximation theorem](http://imgur.com/0wjaV)? I'm interested in understanding the former.

Comment: How is $p_{n,k}$ defined in the former?

Comment: It is defined as $p_{n,k}:=\mathrm{P}\left(N_{\left(0,t/2^n\right]}\geq1\right)$ if $k\in\left\{1,2,\dots,2^n\right\}$ and $p_{n,k}:=0$ otherwise.

Comment: OK, i think i get it now. We *define* $\lambda_n:=2^np_n$, so that  $p_n=\lambda_n/2^n$. It is shown in the proof that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lambda_n=\alpha t\in\mathbb{R}$. So
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} p_{n,k}^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lambda_n^2}{2^n}=0$$ Thanks, Davide!